Identify this movie where man dies but his ghost lingers
I am trying to identify this movie, here is what I remember of it;

It is an old movie, probably 90's
A man (yellow hair I guess) dies, but his ghost lingers
Ghost watches his wife and best friend (but he was actually bad)
Ghost discovers his death was some kind of complo.
Encounter a african-american woman who can hear him, but cannot see
Haunts her (by singing a song about henry) until she agrees to go to talk to man's wife about the man's death
Wife doesn't believe her first, but she convince her by saying things only wife and the man could have possibly know.


Missed to answer this....

Is this a serious question or just an attempt to garner reputation? I find it hard to believe that anyone hasn't heard of Ghost

@APaleShadow I live in Turkey, and I watched it when I was kid on T.V. It is not that popular in here, and I couldn't find it through google.

Pottery is also involved.

The movie you are looking for is Ghost with Patrick Swayze in the title role and Whoopi Goldberg as the medium who speaks to him. I cannot do much else to proove my claim than refer you to Wikipedia to convince yourself that its plot matches your explanations pretty closely.
